# How to optimize the comparison of two lists to reduce the number of updates

Tags: algorithm, sorting, design-patterns, comparison

I am working on an algorithm to compare to lists of ranges.  The setup is simple, but the algorithm is getting more and more complex.  I'm afraid I might be reinventing the wheel here so I thought I would ask the community if this sounds like any design patterns that have already been figured out.

I have two lists to compare.  Each list contains a Boolean - Yes/No, and a range of numbers.  Here's a visual:

**List 1:**

```
Key   Value     Range Start    Range End
-----------------------------------
A1    Y         1              5
A2    N         9              11
A3    Y         13             15
```

**List 2:**

```
Key   Value     Range Start    Range End
-----------------------------------
B1    Y         3              7
B2    N         9              14
```

The goal: to identify the optimal number of changes necessary to make list 1 cover the same ranges as list 2.  In this case it would be: Update A1 to start at 3 and end at 7, Update A2 to end at 12, Update A3 to end at 14. I think this is similar to what a text-comparison algorithm might do.

I've created a rats nest of a flow chart to model this and I'm only half done.  Looking forward to any suggestions that would point me in a better direction.

Update:
I've found some very interesting science around text-comparison algorithms.  I also found [this tutorial](http://simplygenius.net/Article/DiffTutorial1) explaining Eugene Myers' Diff algorithm.

My use case does have some implicit rules regarding the "edit script" that I can generate.

- I do not want to modify Value.  I would prefer to modify the range or delete the entire row and insert a new row to change Value.
- I do not want to move a range start backwards--I would rather insert a new row to accommodate that.  Moving a range start forwards is fine.

Comment: Can you list what are permissible change/update operations? I can think of some but not sure which are allowed like Update Range of key Start, Update Range of key End, Update key Value , Update key, Add a new range with value. Once we have list of allowed operations defined we can think of optimizing the total change operations. Also how do we deal with missing ranges and duplicates, like for example in your example swap list 1 and list 2.

Comment: Can  you explain what "Value" means here? why is it important, why not just consider ranges?